# How do I change my token symbol on substrate-node-template?

Tags: balances, substrate-node-template

I am running the `substrate-node-template` and I notice that the token symbol is `UNIT` and under the accounts tab in polkadot{.js} it shows up as MUNIT. How can I change my token symbol?

Comment: @Keith Yeung.
First, thanks for your article.
I just tried as you mentioned above but I got an error when run "cargo build --release" command.
Here is my error.
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd2jC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd2jC.png) How can I fix this problem?
Please teach me.
Best Regards.

Comment: You need to add the missing import at the top of the file: `use sc_service::Properties`. If you are using the node-template, you can see that there's already an import of the sc_service, so you can extend it like `use sc_service::{ChainType, Properties};` The rust compiler gives really good error handling and details on how to solve it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way you can change your token symbol is in the `chain_spec.rs` file, you can add something like this:

```
let mut properties = Properties::new();
properties.insert("tokenSymbol".into(), "DOT".into());
properties.insert("tokenDecimals".into(), 12.into());
properties.insert("ss58Format".into(), 42.into());
```

For example you can edit your chain_spec's development config like this:

```
pub fn development_config() -> Result<ChainSpec, String> {
    let wasm_binary = WASM_BINARY.ok_or_else(|| "Development wasm not available".to_string())?;
    
    // Give your base currency a unit name and decimal places
    let mut properties = Properties::new();
    properties.insert("tokenSymbol".into(), "DOT".into());
    properties.insert("tokenDecimals".into(), 12.into());
    properties.insert("ss58Format".into(), 42.into());

    Ok(ChainSpec::from_genesis(
        // Name
        "Development",
        // ID
        "dev",
        ChainType::Development,
        move || {
            testnet_genesis(
                wasm_binary,
                // Initial PoA authorities
                vec![authority_keys_from_seed("Alice")],
                // Sudo account
                get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                // Pre-funded accounts
                vec![
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice//stash"),
                    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob//stash"),
                ],
                true,
            )
        },
        // Bootnodes
        vec![],
        // Telemetry
        None,
        // Protocol ID
        None,
        // Properties
        Some(properties),
        // Extensions
        None,
    ))
}
```

Alternatively you can also make this change in the plain chain spec file.
Take a look here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paritytech/polkadot/master/node/service/res/rococo.json

Comment: How to set initial token supply?

Comment: How to specify another different symbol if i have 2 native tokens of different type?

Comment: You would need [pallet assets](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/assets) for that.